# How can I log selected text with Firefox Addon Builder?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have followed several tutorials with no success. I think this is the classic example but I can't make it work. I can save my project, install the addon and I can see the context menu item "Log Selection" when I select some text, but when I click on it nothing happens.

```
exports.main = function() {

    var contextMenu = require("context-menu");
    var request = require("request");
    var selection = require("selection");

    var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
        label: "Log Selection",
        context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
        contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                 '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                 '});',
        onMessage: function (selectionText) {
            alert(selectionText);
        }
    });
}
```

Even if my addon contains only one alert, the addon is installed but the alert is not shown.

```
exports.main = function() {
       alert("Hello world");
}
```

**Extra info:**

- SDK: 1.14 (up to date)
- Add-on Builder Helper: 1.7 (up to date)
- Add On Builder Webpage: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `alert` directly in a lib/ module. There is simply no `window` that could display the alert and hence there is no `alert` function.

Have a look instead at the [Logging documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/logging.html).

Should you really want to display something, you could e.g. use [notifications](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/notifications.html), or `alert` using `nsIPromptService` (example on [this page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/xul-migration.html)) or from within a content document (widget, etc).

Here is [an example showing off different methods](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/199716/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for clarification about alerts! Respect to the logging, that reference is not useful to me because they work directly with the SDK and I'm using the Addon Builder. So I don have a terminal, just the Javascript console of the browser.

Comment: About logging I can't see the error in my code (and it is not my code really, I copied a sample).

Comment: "If you've installed the add-on in Firefox, or you're running the add-on in the Add-on Builder, then the messages appear in Firefox's Error Console."

Comment: Yes, but there is no message in console on my computer

Comment: The problem was that I was using the Webconsole, not error console.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example link for different methods is broken.