# alert window in my firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm fresh to firefox addons development, so pls excuse me if it's too dumb. I just couldnt find the answer here in the Stack.

I try to launch an alert window from my addon:

```
alert('This is an alert');
```

However, it won't recognize 'alert'. What component should I include (Require)?

Thanks!

Comment: I discussed using `alert` in an SDK module here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18234073/484441

Comment: Do you really need to produce an alert, or are you using it for debugging purposes?

Comment: nmaier, thanks. I'll try that
and canuckistani, yes, it's for debugging.

Comment: Better use the new notification mechanism: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this could help you?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/User_Notifications_and_Alerts?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_School%2FUser_Notifications_and_Alerts

Since links occasionally die I'll save you some scrolling and post the code that might be most useful:

```
let alertsService =
  Cc["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIAlertsService);
let title = this._bundle.getString("xulschoolhello.greeting.title");
let message = this._bundle.getString("xulschoolhello.greeting.label");

alertsService.showAlertNotification(
  "chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/hello-notification.png",
  title, message, true, "", this, "XULSchool Hello Message");
```

Comment: The question asks for a modal alert (like window.alert), which alerts-service does not provide

Answer (score 13):

For a modal alert, as the question asks, better to use prompt-service, not alerts-service:

```
var prompts = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPromptService);
prompts.alert(null, "AlertTitle", "AlertMessage");
```

Comment: You might need (if you haven't already) to make the Cc and Ci modules available earlier in you addon script, with this: const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

Comment: @lam Zesh or use const {Services} = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm', null); Services.prompt.alert(null, "AlertTitle", "AlertMessage");