# "Alert" not defined when used hotkey add-ons firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, hotkeys

I have got follow code here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/hotkeys

This my code:

```
var {Hotkey} = require("sdk/hotkeys");

var number =100;

function checkNumber (number) {
    alert(number);
}

var showHotKey = Hotkey({
    combo: "ctrl-shift-o",
    onPress: function() {
        checkNumber(number);
    }
});
var showHotKey = Hotkey({
    combo: "ctrl-Y",
    onPress: function() {
        checkNumber(number);
    }
});
```

Error log:

```
console.error: checkandcall:
JPM [error]   Message: ReferenceError: alert is not defined
  Stack:
    checkNumber@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://checkandcall/index.js:10:2
showHotKey<.onPress@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://checkandcall/index.js:16:3
onKeypress@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/keyboard/hotkeys.js:102:7
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:112:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
handleEvent@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/keyboard/observer.js:53:5
```

So What is this solution?. 
Thanks advanced!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alert window in my firefox addon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235308/alert-window-in-my-firefox-addon)

Comment: @JCOC611 I don't think so. This my problem just in hotkey of firefox. Others, i still "alert" normal.

Comment: Try using the code of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20991599/5620297) from the above question

Comment: Thank you so much!. I solved my mistake. I add :tabs.activeTab.attach
'var showHotKey = Hotkey({
 combo: "alt-x",
 onPress: function() {
  tabs.activeTab.attach({
   contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"),data.url("check-number-hotkey.js")]
  });
 }
}); '
and It executed . Addition, i can write anything in file check-number-hotkey.js ;)